# How do I get Spy++ with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, spy++

#### Background

I am looking for Spy++. I believe it should be included in Visual Studio 2017 since the latest Visual Studio help content references it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment.

#### Problem

I have just done a clean install of Visual Studio 2017, but Spy++ does not exist in the file system. I can't find it.

#### Question

So I guess I need to select certain "workflows" when installing Visual Studio to have Spy++ installed? Anyone know if this is correct? And if so, which workflow/feature do I need?

#### Setup

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio Professional 2017 15.1 (26403.3)

Comment: Good Spies are hard to find...

Answer (score 119, accepted):

1. Open **Visual Studio Installer**
2. Note down which edition of Visual Studio you have installed (eg `Professional` or `Community`)
3. Click **Modify**
4. Click **Individual Components**
5. Locate the **Development activities** heading
6. Check the **Visual Studio C++ core features** component:
   [image: Location]
7. Click **Modify**
8. Spy++ might now reside in the following paths, once you substitute the `{edition}` placeholder with your Visual Studio edition

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\{edition}\Common7\Tools\spyxx.exe
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\{edition}\Common7\Tools\spyxx_amd64.exe
   ```

Comment: Since you seem to use the Professional edition, I would like to point out that the Community edition also has it. For me it is located under: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools`

Comment: @raffamaiden, thanks. I've incorporated that into the answer.

Comment: You can also find it under Tools > Spy ++ after adding it via this method. Whether you're on the community or professional edition.

Comment: As of VS 2017 (Professional), the Visual Studio c++ core features component is located under "Visual Studio extension development" (instead of "Development Activities").

Comment: For VS 2019 (Professional), "Visual Studio C++ core features" was renamed to "C++ core features" and is located under the "Development activities" group.

Comment: For the VS studio 2022 community installation, the spyxx is now at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools and there is no longer a longer 'visual studio c++' to select it manually. It is installed by default.

Comment: For VS 2022 Community, it is not installed by default (I just did a new install). However, installing "C++ core features" does install it, as described above.

Answer (score 7):

It's part of the C++ profiling tools component.

Comment: I think it's actually part of the C++ core features component, since that's the only C++ related feature I've installed.

Comment: @Jimmy I installed the C# workload and then modified the installation to add the C++ profiling tools which added Spy++ I did try a couple of other options first but that's the one which added it for me

Comment: @Jimmy, I just checked it out and it looks like you're right. C++ profiling tools depends on C++ core features, which explains why adding C++ profiling tools added Spy++. If you make that into an answer, I can accept it instead of this one.

Comment: I had `Visual Studio C++ core features` installed, but no spyxx. I added `C++ profiling tools`, and only that, and it appeared. Go figure, maybe those two packages, depending on other selections, may have a 3rd common dependency that installs it?! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I've got both `Visual Studio C++ core features` and `C++ profiling tools` installed, and still don't have Spy++.